# Is using a platform like Chegg helpful for studying?

Tags: calculus

Previously, I used a platform like Chegg, a homework helping website to do math problems out of the back of a book for one of my math courses in college. Does this style of studying hurt me from actually learning or do you think this is a good way to learn?

Comment: Someday, there will be no answer book. Those who struggled will learn how to adapt and come to answers because they lived it. Sometimes, I even hate MSE for this very reason.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

Doing Practive Problems is never really a bad way to spend your time learning. However you should keep in mind that it is possible that you could have learned "more" by doing something else. This is especially the case if you do lots and lots of the same style of question, in an area where you actually have the fundamentals down and are basically just flexing your existing problem solving muscle. When you get stumped often though, then you clearly are in need to review some of the fundamentals of that particular subject, as they are pertaining to the question. In a case, when most practice problems of a similar nature become rather boring you should actively look to either progress to the next chapters (where most of the time you will see that whatever you just mastered is just a small building block of the next thing) or study another area you are interested in.

Since I am not sure what your education level is right now I am basing this on a college level standpoint. It will not benefit you at all to just mindlessly practice derrivates of simple polynoms because tbh. that should be trivial to you by now. Furthermore it is something you will probably need in a lot of your other clases so it kind of gets practiced "along the way" anyways. Therefore it would be a bad use of your time here.